# Youtrack like text styling

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to style my input text fields in a way that if I type two words in the input field , the bottom border of first word is black and for the second word its red (similar to youtrack). Any hints would be welcome

Comment: Hi Catalin actually i am not a JS developer i am html designer so i tried in html and css and i dinot get any solution so i put here my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. I have prepared a demo for you because i liked the question :D.It is badly implemented as it doesnot support special keys, But this is surely a starting point for you .

Here is js fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/madterry/jwq53/

HTML :

```
 Enter :<div id="madText" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

CSS :

```
#madText {
    border-left: 1px solid darkgray;
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 398px;    
}
```

jQuery :

```
  $('#madText').on('keyup',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Find all child span & replace with text
    $(this).find('span').each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
    });

    //Find all words
    var words = $(this).html().trim().split(' ');

    //Clear the data 
    $(this).html('');
    //for all words
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        //Even odd game :D
       if ((i+1)%2 == 0) {
         $(this).append(' <span style="border-bottom: 3px solid;border-bottom-color:red;">' + words[i] + '</span>');
       } else {
        $(this).append(' <span style="border-bottom: 3px solid;border-bottom-color:green;">' + words[i] + '</span>');
       }
    }
    //Set cursor to end
    if($(this).find('span').length>0) setCursorToEnd($(this).find('span').last()[0]);

 return false;
});

//Foun it on google :D
function setCursorToEnd(ele)
  {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(ele, 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    ele.focus();
  }
```

Comment: Hi MADTerry thanks for your help. Only the thing is when i type the cursor is not movingwith the text but it has tobe so please can u help me.

Comment: It still has issue like arrow keys are not movable.

Comment: Okie , MADTerry did u check the link of jsfiddle page, i dont know how it was deleted.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/madterry/jwq53/